# How can i use SecurityContext in Jax-RS to get Token of a specified user?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs

Can i do this? I am using SecurityContext of Jax-rs to get current Student

```
 @GET 
    @Secured
    @Path("/books") 
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Book> getBooks(@Context SecurityContext securityContext){ 
        Student s = (Student)securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
        TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s.books from Student s where s.token = :token", Book.class);
        query.setParameter("token", s.getToken());
        List<Book> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if yours is working. I have implemented the security handling with spring security and it works fine like this. It's similar but not the same.

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

User loggedinUser = null;

if (authentication != null) {
    Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
    loggedinUser = principal instanceof SpringSecurityUser ? ((SpringSecurityUser)principal).getUser() : null;
}
```

In this example you can access a token or password or whatever now with

```
String token = loggedinUser.getToken();
```